# i am having trouble with a snippet of code, what command should i use?

Tags: netlogo

An error in compilation is caused by the lack of a command before speed limit. What command should I use ? I have tried this, but it does not work because it is only for agent sets. The code is as follows

```
set speed-limit-of mouse-patch  SPEED_LIMIT * 1000 / (60 * 60)
```

Comment: Please edit your question so that it says what the actual error message was. Never ask for help and just say "an error", always always always always always provide the exact text of the error message.

Comment: the error message said that a command was needed before speed limit

Comment: no. the exact text of the error message. always the exact text. never just some paraphrase. use copy and paste. details matter in programming.

Comment: also, please edit your question to improve it, rather than just tacking comments on.

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately the -of syntax has become obsolete. I think it was swell.

Try 
Set [speed-limit] of mouse-patch

Comment: yes as I feared. I am new to net logo as you can tell but I have a specific goal in mind and I wonder if you could possibly help with this. I wish to create a road network builder first and foremost, and I feel that the model I am looking at now achieves this in the most practical and simple manner, however the only problem is it is in logo 3.1. And despite downloading netlogo3.1 the compiler still comes across various problems, alas this is beside the point. I wonder if it would be possible to sort of translate the old code into new?

Comment: I am not sure if there is but that is the major difference. Does your code work now?

Comment: No it is really bugging me, I am starting to get to grips with what the code is saying but converting from an older code form to a newer code form at this early stage is too much I feel.

Comment: I am here to help if you need it. What model are you messing with?

Comment: I am messing with a model by Andrew Lansdowne called Traffic simulation using agent-based modelling the source code is available off his pages. The part of his program that most interests me is the ability to draw out circuits for cars to travel along and some of the underlying dynamics for the cars.

Comment: Nope http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58713/how-can-i-pm-people-on-this-site

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63677/discussion-between-pac3mobile-and-king-ink).